# No 'comment' button for new users shows

Tags: support, comments, privileges

How much reputation (If this is the qualifier) do you need to have to make comments on questions to ask possible clarification questions, etc?

One of my answers got deleted understandably because it wasn't really an answer, but a comment.  But there was no way to make a comment.

<strike>I tagged it as bug as it surprised me that I would be unable to comment.</strike>

Comment: I've converted your answer to [a comment](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/173313/where-is-the-best-resources-to-learn-ruby#comment331228_173313). It was a bit long to fit in a comment, so I removed your opening paragraph that wasn't really relevant. Please refrain from posting comments as answers, you'll get to 50 rep very soon ;)

Comment: Awesome... (and now at over the required rep)  Thank you Yannis!

Comment: You're welcome. For the record the rep requirement for comments is _mostly_ an anti-spam mechanism. Comments aren't peer reviewed like questions and answers are, they are extremely less visible and may go undetected for a while. BTW you just got the association bonus, so now you can comment everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [50 points](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) to be able to comment on any question or answer.

You can comment on your own posts or answers to your own questions with [1 point](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-posts).

Answer (score 1):

You need [50 reputation to comment everywhere](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). You can comment on your own questions or answers or on other people's answers to your questions regardless of your reputation.